# How can I see the Oracle APEX App builder page? (Oracle APEX 21.1)

Tags: oracle-apex

There!

I am looking for the screen of Oracle APEX App builder.

Oracle DB and APEX are in my development environment. But instead of the familiar App builder screen, it show me the Administration service.
I was able to create a workspace. Which menu should I use to import the Application that I exported from my previous environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Administration" is opened if you connect to `internal` workspace using the `admin` user. Such a login screen contains only two fields to be entered: username and password and is behind such a URL:

```
http://your_server:port/ords/apex_admin
```

In order to login as an "ordinary" user to your workspace, remove the "apex_admin" part:

```
http://your_server:port/ords/
```

Once you're connected, go to "App Builder" and click the "Import" button.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!! :D
I met a Application Builder screen! 
I create a new developer account and  login by that user.
If you hadn't told me, I would have locked myself away at work to face tomorrow :D